# Does docusign webhooks notify about template changes

Tags: docusignapi

Use Case -

We are an origanization who helps universities manage the sport activities and contract of their students. We are planning to integrate docusign in our system both web and mobile app. One feature that we need is the information regarding the created templates, is there a way to get notified about templates via webhooks(like when it was last used, or created).

Answer (score 1):

So, webhooks may not be suitable to know when a new template is created, because currently the webhook is tied to an existing object, and the object is not yet there, so it's a catch22.

What you can use instead is the [DocuSign Monitor API](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/monitor-api/). It's a different approach, but using this API, you can get data about anything that happens in the DocuSign account, including templates.

You can make raw API calls, or use the [Monitor SDKs](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/monitor-api/sdk-tools/) for one of six languages.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% on this but one approach would be to use folders. Put your templates in a named folder and use the listStatusChanges API with a folder id as a query parameter (https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/list-envelope-status-changes/)

You can also select "Folders" in the "Include Data:" section of your DocuSign Connect webhook and filter for the folder(s) you're looking for.[image: Connect Custom Configuration -- Folders]

Comment: Note: For Connect, you would still need to select a trigger event. "Envelopes Sent" will give you all the envelopes sent, then you can filter for the Folder ID in the returned JSON.